# I have executed the below code to print the number in an array which occurs odd number times. But this codes print the last element of the array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I think the problem is int this line "num = A[i]" I have tried to assign the num as zero. But could not accomplish.

```
public static int solution(int A[]){
    int num = A[0];
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<A.length ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<A.length; j++) {
            if(A[i] == A[j]) {
                count++;
            }
            if(count%2 != 0)
                num = A[i];
            else
                count = 0;
        }
    }
    return num;
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = {10,22,345,22,345,10,5};
    System.out.println(solution(arr));

}
```

Comment: `num` shouldn't be assigned in in the inner loop. You can't know the number of occurrences until you go through the entire array. Also, `count` needs to be reset in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this and track multiple solutions:

```
Set<Integer> odds = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i : A) {
    if (odds.contains(i)) {
        odds.remove(i);
    } else {
        odds.add(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(odds);
```

Comment: Could you please help me how to write to return statament as String?

Comment: return odds.toString

Comment: I forgot to ask for int return type. How about the int return type?

Comment: This returns all instances of odd number of entries in the array, so you need to decide which item in the set you want to return.  If it's just the first item then instead of doing the remove, just return that number. Alternatively, you could make it a LinkedHashSet instead  of a HashSet and then return the first item.